# Data table excel button not show on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I have one data table excel but it not show on my page.

My Code:

```php
     <style>
      .buttons-excel{
            margin-left: 23px;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script href=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script href=" https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

      <table id="all_sub" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%;" >
       <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
             <th>Subscriber Name</th>
             <th>Course Name</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php foreach($allsubscriber as $allsub):?>
       <tr>
       <td><?php echo $allsub->user_firstname;?></td>
       <td><?php echo $allsub->course_title;?></td>
     </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>              
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#all_sub').DataTable( {
         "pageLength": 50,
           dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: [
                 { extend: 'excel', text: 'export to excel &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>'  }
            ]
    } );
    } );
    </script>
```

I think everything is fine in my code but I do not know where I am wrong in my code.
It was working before I do not know what happens.

Comment: Does button exists if you remove `text` description?

Comment: @AksenP no not exists

Comment: `datatables.buttons.js` is missing. Include all the files from [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html) with same order and `table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );`